# MSHTML fallback for data uri:s

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, mshtml, data-uri

My site uses data uri:s to reduce the number of HTTP requests to my site. The problem is that data uri:s don't work in IE7, a browser that we have to support (No, we don't need IE6). I've followed [Stoyan's guide](http://www.phpied.com/the-proper-mhtml-syntax/) and actually gotten it to work, but after a recent Microsoft security update (KB2544893, as descibed in a [comment on the original article](http://www.phpied.com/the-proper-mhtml-syntax/#comment-78586)) the fallback seems to have stopped working.

The comment referenced above suggests I should try sending the MSHTML file with Content-Type message/rfc822, but I can't get this to work either, and I've tried multiple different ways over a course of several hours.

**So my question is this**: Can you get the technique described by Stoyan to work somehow? I would really appreciate a working example to convince me that it truly is possible.

Comment: Can you confirm what web server you're running? Also can you confirm that you're serving the file with an .mht extension rather than .css?

Comment: I'm happy if someone can get this method to work in ANY way, on ANY webserver out there. If I have one working version I can easily interpolate to my own setup (which is nginx/Django). Yes, I've tried setting the filetype to .mht without success.

Comment: So if you're using that extension... can you open up Firebug within Firefox or Chrome Dev Tools and confirm what comes back in the HTTP Headers for your request to "yourfile.mht" ? - If it says Content-Type: message/rfc822 then you have categorical proof that it will not work. As you've done literally everything mentioned in each article on this.

Comment: This question is about finding someone knowledgeable that tries things and confirms of denies if it works or not. I know that it doesn't work in my setup already.

Comment: 1. The only documented solution for this (that I can find on Google) is the one you've linked to. 2. That solution requires that you ensure that the response header 'Content-Type' says 'message/rfc822' - does it? 3. The article also states that you should use a file extension of 'mht' - you've said that you do. 4. If both 2 and 3 are followed, then there is no other documented solution available and it therefore does not work. More importantly, any web developer would tell you this is a bad, non-compliant 'solution/hack' even if it did work (i.e. something that is broken by a windows update).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got in contact with Stoyan Stefanov (the original author of the technique), and he fixed his original example so it now works. Simply adding "message/rfc822" as content-type was all that's needed.

Fixed example: http://www.phpied.com/files/datasprites/testhover2.html

I asked him to post a comment here so I could award the points, but he didn't want to.

Comment: Stoyan, the man! // yet, this does not remove my point about using this hack in general.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use conditional styles. In your main markup - start it as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

In your css you can now do:

```
.myClass {
      background-image: url(/*DATAURI GOES HERE*/);
}
```

and

```
.ie7 .myClass {
      background-image: url(fallback-image.png);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Further to the comments below, if you're concerned around IE7 performance - a reliable approach would be to make your IE7 [fallback image a sprite](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/).

That way you're only making 1 additional HTTP call for IE7 users:

```
.ie7 .myClass {
      background-image: url(fallback-sprite.png);
      background-position: 150px 15px;
}
```

Comment: That would mean that the slowest browser, IE7, would get no benefit at all from this optimization.

Comment: Based on usage statistics for IE7 I would say that the benefits gained from less Development/Maintenance costs outweighs the cost to IE7 users having a less performant experience

Comment: We sell a service, claim to be IE7 compliant, and have about 5% IE7 users. We have about 20.000 monthly users, which means 1000 users that will have IE7. What I'm asking for here is a way to help those 1000 users have a better experience.

Comment: IE7 compliance I get - and you're already there by using an image fallback. 

However you cannot make IE7 something its not: by that, I mean even if you make data-uris work with a hack of some kind - your IE7 users will still have worse performance due to its below-standard rendering capabilities and JavaScript engine - you can't swap those out, so you cannot truly achieve what you want. 

If you're really worried about performance in IE7 - use a sprite image, which then means there is only 1 HTTP request extra for your IE7 users (I've updated my answer to include this).

Comment: We have considered sprite images. The problem with them is that they are a nightmare to maintain. "- Can you make that icon a little bit larger?", "- Yes, I'll just rebuild the whole sprite". I will probably fall back to either individual images or sprites, but not before I know that the MSHTML technique is impossible. It provides the same performance characteristics as data uris, using the same basic idea (base64 encoding), which makes it as easy to maintain.

Comment: sending them .mht files will **not** improve their experience. Just serve those poor people images. // And, preferably, images with "update your IE" ads ;)

Comment: @c69: Yes, it will improve their experience. Fewer HTTP requests is one of the top client side performance tricks there is. Although I agree it won't improve their experience as much as them upgrading... But that's not very likely is it? ;)

Comment: @Emil, i don't know what could be a reason other than corporate stupidity to use IE7, because upgrade to IE8 is **free**. And both browsers are available on winXP and not available on earlier systems (like win2000).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/ here's your solution i think

Comment: No. The article I link to in the question is the follow-up to the one you link to. Try that demo in IE7 and you'll see it doesn't work.